# How to leave 2 digits in printf using %d

Tags: c

```
main ()
{
    int a; // Dabartine data
    int b; // Gimimo data
    int c;
    printf("Iveskite dabartine data formatu yymmdd:");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    printf("Iveskite savo gimimo data formatu yymmdd:");
    scanf("%d", &b);
    c = a - b;
    printf("Jusu amzius yra %d metai", c);
    return 0;
}
```

Could someone tell me how to make that in the end the result would be only 2 digits? It is a code to calculate your age accordingly to current date and date of birth. The answer is in yymmdd format and I need to remove the mmdd part and leave only the year part, for example: it prints 180602, and I only need to leave 18(it is the age of person)

Comment: Can you demonstrate *any* effort at solving this yourself?

Comment: Google or man printf

Comment: This question is not actually about printing `4` as `04` or anything. I think it's asking how to turn `920915` into `92`.

Comment: ^^ exactly I need to turn let's say 180602 to 18

Comment: @melpomene - if that is the case, divide the value by `10000` and print that.  The indicated duplicate is relevant then.

Comment: You could add example to the question to show it's not a duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try `c = (a - b)/10000;`
That will discard the last 4 digits without rounding up.

Comment: Thanks, damn I'm stupid couldn't think of this simple solution ://